# Rails form won't submit self-referential form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form that adds a product to the cart. It's a simple form that sends a POST request to /products/1/add_to_cart

It all works well when I'm on the /products/1 page and I'm submitting the form to add the product to the cart. It doesn't, however, work when I've added the product to the cart and then try to add it again. I get a 'no route matches "/products/1/add_to_cart"' error.

When submitting the form from /products/1, it succeeds and the logs show:

> Started POST "/products/1/add_to_cart" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-07-04 16:10:27 -0600
>   
> Processing by ProductsController#add_to_cart as HTML

After this request, the item has been added to the cart and the controller action calls a render :action => 'show' (to keep the validation errors of adding the item to the cart). The URL is now /products/1/add_to_cart

When trying to submit the form again (from /products/1/add_to_cart) to add the item to the cart a second time, I get a routing Error:

> Started POST "/products/1/add_to_cart" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-07-04 16:13:05
>   -0600 ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/products/1/add_to_cart"):

**Am I missing something here? Why won't Rails find the route if I'm submitting the form from the URL the form will be processed by (ie: /products/1/add_to_cart submits a form to /products/1/add_to_cart)?**

**-----UPDATE------**

Per-request, here is the related route:

```
resource :store, :only => [:show], :controller => 'Store' do
  resources :products, :except => [:index], :shallow => true do
    member do
      post :add_to_cart
    end
  end
end
```

Here is the (slimmed down) controller:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @cart_item = CartItem.new
  end

  def add_to_cart
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    @cart_item = CartItem.new(params[:cart_item])
    @cart_item.product = @product
    if @cart_item.save
      current_cart.items << @cart_item
      flash[:notice] = 'This item was added to your cart.'
    end
    render :action => :show
  end
end
```

Comment: could you post your routes.rb and products controller code...

Comment: Generally speaking, the Rails style would be to redirect to the "show" action after processing "add_to_cart" rather than rendering it. I don't know if that will fix your problem, it's just a style note.

Comment: Hi @Rafe. The problem with redirecting is I'll lose all the validation errors I had on CartItem. Any good way around that?